# How to rename a file name without change its type?

Tags: java, file-handling

I have doubt in renaming java files... My application has to rename the incoming file which is mdb,dbf,xls,xml,etc. format. I used the following source code.

eg:

```
String filename = "D:/sample.mdb";
File filediriden = new File(filename);
String[] filetype = filename.split("\\.");
System.out.println("Filetype :"+filetype[1]);
String newfilename = "D:/new."+filetype[1];
File newfilediriden = new File(newfilename);
System.out.println("New File Name "+newfilename);
boolean rename = filediriden.renameTo(newfilediriden);
if(rename)
   System.out.println("File Renamed");
if(filediriden.isFile()){
    System.out.println("filename" + filediriden.getName());
}else{
    System.out.println("not a filename");
}
```

---

```
OUTPUT:
Filetype  : mdb
New File Name D:/new.mdb
File Renamed
not a filename
```

After that I checked whether its a file or not but its not going into that...Help plz...

Comment: pls format that stuff properly :)

Comment: Could you please improve your formatting and actually ask a question? It seems you already solved your problem.

Comment: Pls format the above code well.

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean rename = filediriden.renameTo(newfilediriden);
if(filediriden.isFile()){
```

After you rename the file, the old File object (*filediriden*) still points to the old name, which no longer exists. You want to check using the new File object (*newfilediriden*).

```
filetype[1]
```

Also, there could be files with more than one dot in them, so maybe *filetype[filetype.length-1]* is safer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're checking the filedirden instead of newfiledirden.
At the point of test, filedirden doesn't exist anymore, as the file it points to was renamed.